# NameError: name 'price' is not defined

Tags: python

I've stumbled across an error which seems pretty simple to fix but I just cant suss it.
Basically having a play around trying to make a discord bot.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
from math import trunc
import random

paypal = round((price * 0.029 + 0.30), 2)
stockx = round((price * 0.095), 2)
stockx2 = round((price * 0.09), 2)
stockx3 = round((price * 0.085), 2)
stockx4 = round((price * 0.08), 2)
goat = round((price * 0.095 + 5), 2)
ebay = round((price * 0.129 + 0.30), 2)

class General(commands.Cog, name = "Fees Cog"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        print("Loaded Fees Cog.")

@commands.command(name='fees', help = 'Check sale fees for different platforms.')
async def suggest(self, ctx, message):
    if self.bot.delete_commands:
        await ctx.message.delete()

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Fees Calculator",
        color = random.choice(bot.embed_colors),
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name = "PayPal (2.9% + £0.30)",
        value = "£{}".format(paypal),
        inline = False
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name = "StockX (8-9.5% + 3%)",
        value = "Level 1 (9.5%) - £{}\nLevel 2 (9%) - £{}\nLevel 3 (8.5%) - £{}\nLevel 4 (8%) - £{}".format(stockx, stockx2, stockx3, stockx4),
        inline = False
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name = "Goat (9.5% + £5)",
        value = "£{}".format(goat),
        inline = False
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name = "eBay (10% + PayPal Fees)",
        value = "£{}".format(ebay),
        inline = False
    )
    embed.set_footer(
        text = self.bot.footer_text,
        icon_url = self.bot.footer_icon
    )

    for log in self.bot.command_channel:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(log)
        await channel.send(content = None, embed = embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(General(bot))
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. But yes, you're referring to `price` before it's been defined - it's not clear what you expected would happen.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you clearly that you are using undefined variables at the top where you define the globals.

Comment: You haven't define price anywhere in your code.

Comment: You can delete everything except line 6 and still get the exact same error. Read @jonrsharpe's link above.

Answer (score 1):

The python code executes line by line, and when it reaches **line # 6** which has `paypal = round((price * 0.029 + 0.30), 2)`, the variable `price` is not defined at that point.

Comment: It isn't even defined later.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, even if it was defined later, the exception gets thrown.